# Dimension of the embedding matrix in a transformer during inference

Tags: transformer, inference

I have a bit of confusion understanding the dimensions of the input embedding matrix at inference time in transformers. Some sources say that you start with an  token and you fill with  tokens up to some max length parameter (which max length and how do you decide that???), some other sources say you fill with  tokens until again some max length. Which is the right one? Why wouldn't make sense to make it dynamic? (1xn_embeddings at first step, 2xn_embeddings at second step and so on...)

And let's say the PAD way is the right one, at the end of the decoding step we would have a matrix of dimensions (max_length x n_embeddings). To compute the next token, do we consider only the row of the output matrix related to the last predicted token, and argmax over it?

Thanks in advance for your answers, I hope the questions are clear!